# Pra que serve explicit em C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, operadores, c++11

Me deparei com o termo `explicit` sendo usado em um código C++.

Qual a utilidade desta palavra-chave?

Comment: Não vou colar na resposta, mas veja aqui: http://renangreinert.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/palavra-magica-e-explicit.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Operador de *cast*

Ele é usado junto com a declaração de um operador de *cast*.

Imagino que saiba que C++ permite que se defina operadores para um tipo, assim a sintaxe de certas operações fica mais próxima do que as pessoas estão acostumadas com a matemática tradicional ou aquela já usada em programação.

Um desses operadores é o *cast*, que é a conversão de um tipo para outro. A operação pode ser só uma reinterpretação do dado ou ter que mudar seu conteúdo. Pode ser uma operação simples ou complexa (transformar um texto em número é complexa).

Tem duas formas de usar esse operador, uma é explicitamente e outra é implícita. A forma de fazer cada uma pode variar. Se for implícito é a conversão que o próprio compilador identifica que precisa e chama o operador por conta própria. A forma explícita é quando o programador colocou lá no código para garantir que a conversão será feita.

Já que tem dois operadores, tem que identificar quando é um e quando é o outro. O explícito é determinado com a palavra-chave [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit). O [implícito é determinado por um método apenas com o nome do tipo sem uma palavra-chave específica](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

```
operator int() const { return 0; } //obviamente é só exemplo, não está convertendo nada
```

Este seria o operador de *cast* para um tipo `int`. Usaria assim:

```
int x = (int)variavel_do_tipo_que_tem_o_operador; //x valeria 0 nesse exemplo
```

Obviamente precisa ter um operador para cada tipo que deseja prover uma conversão.

Só está disponível no C++11 pra frente.

Mais sobre o [operador de *cast*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

## Construtor

A palavra-chave é usada em outra situação de declaração de método construtor que se exige a [inicialização direta](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

A inicialização direta é a construção de um objeto exclusivamente através da sintaxe de métodos que todos conhecem.

A indireta é uma forma em que a inicialização pode ocorrer através da atribuição de valor ao objeto. Isto nem sempre é desejável. Pode esconder o fato que aquilo é um construtor.

Então um construtor explícito desabilita a construção indireta

```
Foo f(2); //forma explícita/direta de chamada do construtor
Foo f2 = 2; //forma implícita/indireta de chamada do construtor
```

Usando

```
explicit Foo(int) { }
```

Só a primeira chamada seria possível.

## Exemplo completo:

```
struct A {
    A(int) { }      // construtor de conversão
    A(int, int) { } // construtor de conversão (C++11)
    operator int() const { return 0; } // operador de cast implícito
};
 
struct B {
    explicit B(int) { }
    explicit B(int, int) { }
    explicit operator int() const { return 0; }
};
 
int main() {
    A a1 = 1;      // OK: copy-initialization chama A::A(int)
    A a2(2);       // OK: direct-initialization chama A::A(int)
    A a3 {4, 5};   // OK: direct-list-initialization chama A::A(int, int)
    A a4 = {4, 5}; // OK: copy-list-initialization chama A::A(int, int)
    int na1 = a1;  // OK: copy-initialization chama A::operator int()
    int na2 = static_cast<int>(a1); // OK: static_cast faz a inicialização
    A a5 = (A)1;   // OK: explicit cast faz o static_cast
 
//  B b1 = 1;      // error: copy-initialization  B::B(int) não permitida
    B b2(2);       // OK: direct-initialization chama B::B(int)
    B b3 {4, 5};   // OK: direct-list-initialization chama B::B(int, int)
//  B b4 = {4, 5}; // error: copy-list-initialization B::B(int,int) não permitida
//  int nb1 = b2;  // error: copy-initialization B::operator int() não permitida
    int nb2 = static_cast<int>(b2); // OK: static_cast faz a inicialização
    B b5 = (B)1;   // OK: explicit cast faz o static_cast
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/Explicit.cpp).

Comment: Oi bigown. A resposta tá boa, mas acho que dava pra melhorar (a parte antes do construtor, particularmente) com alguns exemplos de uso. Pra pessoas mais experientes eu acho que tá claro, mas não sei se tá suficientemente claro pro AP (aliás, ele podia já dar algum feedback nesse sentido, né Sérgio?). :)

Comment: Não coloquei porque tem na documentação. Vou bolar alguma coisa depois.

Comment: Na verdade estou tentando gravar a alteração há algum tempo e não vai. O site anda problemático em algumas situações.

Comment: Sim, achei que a resposta ficou muito boa! Realmente um exemplo ajudaria muito, mas pra mim já deu pra entender. Agora o processo é esse mesmo, se muita gente visitar a pergunta vamos melhorando o texto, se ninguém visitar nos concentramos mais nas outras perguntas! Boa observação Luiz :)

Comment: "Só está disponível no C++11 pra frente." Olhando superficialmente me parece que esta afirmação está errada. A palavra chave explicit já existia no C++03.

Comment: @JoséX. tem alguma referência? A documentação que eu *linkei* informa só o C++11. Ela existia em outro contexto (o segundo caso que apontei).

Comment: ok, realmente tem um caso que apareceu só no C++11.